# Random BSOD with New PC Build

Tags: windows-7, bsod

The BSOD's I am getting seem to be totally random (and varying).

Here is what is in the case:

MB: ASUS M4A77T/USB3 AM3 AMD 770 USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard
Processor: AMD Athlon II X4 635 Propus 2.9GHz Socket AM3 95W Quad-Core

RAM: G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1066

Video: SAPPHIRE 100296HDMI Radeon HD 4670 1GB 128-bit DDR3

HD: HITACHI Deskstar 1TB 7200 RPM SATA

CD/DVD: LITE-ON CD/DVD Burner

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

I have updated the drivers on everything I can think of and I still get blue screens randomly.

It's all new parts, so how do I go about trying to single out if something is bad?

What do I need to check next to get this thing working consistantly?

Comment: What are the blue screens telling you? Are there any dumps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is to check the RAM. Run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for a few hours or longer.

Comment: If MemTest comes back with any errors, I assume that means my RAM is bad, correct? When I ran with 1 stick in Memtest it almost instantly popped up like 6 errors. One bad stick of RAM out of the two would make sense as to the times the errors are showing up. It seems like when I put the machine under heavy load it would become crash-tastic.

Comment: They tend to indicate errors in the RAM, assuming there isn't a problem with the chipset. Does it run clean with the other stick?

Comment: The other stick runs clean. I am going to leave the machine up in Windows all day today, with Memtest on a USB drive, so if the sucker reboots while I am at work, I'll come home to it running Memtest again and know it hates me in some other way too. Otherwise though, I am hopeful that the RAM was my problem. I have built a lot of computers just nothing very recently, and this random BSOD was starting to make me miss DOS. :)

Comment: Well, the FIRST thing to check is that everything's seated correctly ;)